# How do i use DocFX to generate c# documentation from source code without VS2017?

Tags: docfx

I am trying to follow the [tutorial](http://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/docfx_getting_started.html) from the command line.  I have generated the project and deployed the blank website then added a vs2012 project to the source folder maintaining the original heirarchy.  I have edited the docfx.json file to include "src/**.csproj"  "src/**.cs*" which i assume are searched recursively.  The project was previously commented for use with SandCastle so there should be plenty to extract or generate metadata from.  I currently have vs2012 msdn installed.  My issue is that the metadata never builds and even when I'm using the sample seed project all the md files show up on the webhost but not the documentation from the source files.

Comment: You you post your docfx.json and your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to have the complete VS2017 installed, instead you can just install the build tools of VS2017. [Download](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)

Just start a developer prompt for VS2017 environment and do docfx from there,  it should then be able to extract metadata.  I had problems with VB.NET projects with docfx and older Visual Studio tooling for some reason.